# Cannot set delegate to reload table view

Tags: swift, delegates, tableview, nstableview

I am trying to reload a table view with the help of a delegate. I found tons of examples here on stack overflow, but I always end up with an error.

My first controller which should update the table view:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

    var tableViewData: [[String:String]] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        self.tableView.delegate = self as NSTableViewDelegate
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        }
    }

    func reloadTableData(_ notification: Notification) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return tableViewData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?{
        var result:CustomTableCellview
        result  = tableView.make(withIdentifier: (tableColumn?.identifier)!, owner: self) as! CustomTableCellview
        result.textField?.stringValue = tableViewData[row][(result.textField?.identifier!)!]!
        result.secondTextField?.stringValue = tableViewData[row][result.secondTextField.identifier!]!
        return result
    }
}

extension ViewController: PageControllerDelegate {
    func updateTableData() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

My second controller, which should tell the first one it can update the table view:

```
import Cocoa

protocol PageControllerDelegate {
    func updateTableData()
}

class PageController: NSPageController {

    var delegate: PageControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func saveData(sender: NSButton) {
        ...
        delegate?.updateTableData()
        self.dismiss(self)
    }
}
```

Within the PageController I get the following error:

`Property 'delegate' with type 'PageControllerDelegate?' cannot override a property with type 'NSPageControllerDelegate?' (aka 'Optional<NSPageControllerDelegate>')`

Answer (score 0):

Rename the delegate protocol name to something like MyPageControllerDelegate. It seems like there is already something called PageControllerDelegate that is defined either by you, or Apple

Comment: Unfortunately, the error remains: Property 'delegate' with type 'MyPageControllerDelegate?' cannot override a property with type 'NSPageControllerDelegate?' (aka 'Optional<NSPageControllerDelegate>')

Answer (score 0):

`NSPageController` already has a property `delegate` of type `NSPageControllerDelegate`. Remove `var delegate: PageControllerDelegate?`.

Comment: Ok. But how to I call the `updateTableData()` then? I can access the `NSPageControllerDelegate` via `self.delegate` in func `saveData`, but this delegate does not know the func `updateTableData()`.